# Errors with updates, upgrades, autoremove Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 since 2018. Almost all updates/upgrades have been performed from Software Updater. During the updates I get:

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.19) ...  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic: No such file or directory  
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

And at the end:

[image]

After restart (it is asked):

[image]

Some weeks ago I started a [new thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2446788) that ended in 58 posts without a solution. We tried to clean-remove old kernels but `sudo apt-get full-upgrade` always ends in:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems that something is invoking vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic, an old kernel.  We couldn't find what it is.

Results of `uname -a` :

```
4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo apt update
```

```
Hit:1 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]
Get:3 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
Get:5 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]  
Hit:6 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
Hit:7 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                      
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Get:9 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [1.032 kB]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Get:11 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [723 kB]
Get:12 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [295 kB]
Get:13 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [11,0 kB]
Get:14 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [84,7 kB]
Get:15 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1.097 kB]
Get:16 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [1.027 kB]
Get:17 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [279 kB]
Get:18 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [19,2 kB]
Get:19 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [8.516 B]
Get:20 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.468 B]
Get:21 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9.288 B]
Get:22 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [46,0 kB]
Get:23 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [49,2 kB]
Get:24 http://repos.interior.edu.uy/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.464 B]
Fetched 4.938 kB in 5s (1.064 kB/s)                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic (4.15.0-111.112) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic (4.15.0-112.113) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-108-generic (4.15.0-108.109) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.19) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.15.0.112.100); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-generic; however:
  Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic (4.15.0-111.112) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-111-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch Fix-build-for-4.4.patch...patching file hal/hal_btcoex.c
patching file hal/hal_com.c
patching file hal/hal_com_phycfg.c
patching file include/hal_com.h
patching file include/rtw_debug.h
patching file Makefile
patching file os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c


Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=4.15.0-111-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl8192eu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-111-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/4.4/build/make.log for more information.
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-111-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo:
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic (4.15.0-112.113) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-112-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch Fix-build-for-4.4.patch...patching file hal/hal_btcoex.c
patching file hal/hal_com.c
patching file hal/hal_com_phycfg.c
patching file include/hal_com.h
patching file include/rtw_debug.h
patching file Makefile
patching file os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c


Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=4.15.0-112-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl8192eu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-112-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/4.4/build/make.log for more information.
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo:
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-108-generic (4.15.0-108.109) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.15.0-108-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.15.0-108-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.15.0-108-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-108-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo:
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-108-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-108-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-108-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hmmm. Bashing-om is a wise old bird. If he couldn't figure it out, then there is a distinct possibility that we might do no better.

Comment: Looking thru your link on Ubuntu forums, I agree that you're not likely to get any further here.  I suggest that you reinstall the OS if this problem is stopping you from using your PC effectively. I agree that you might have run out of space on /boot especially if you are not keeping up with updates and autoremoving old kernels and orphaned software

Comment: @Nmath Maybe there was a time when /boot ran out of space, I don't know. In this system I've been use System Update, not shell commands, until I started with checks as suggested in Ubuntu forums.  I don't have problems using this system.  Anyway someday I will perform an OS upgrade

Comment: I upgraded to 20-04 last year